# Spring getting error in get attribute method

Tags: java, spring

I want setting the attribute in first modelandview method with the help of bean and trying to get the attributes in other modelandview method in same controller but getting null value my code is below

@RequestMapping(value="/insert",method=RequestMethod.POST)

```
        public ModelAndView inserData(@ModelAttribute    SavingBeansavingBean,HttpServletRequestrs,Model m) {


 System.out.println(savingBean.getFirstName());





 if (savingBean != null)
  System.out.println("abho");
 SavingBean saving =  persionalService.insertData(savingBean);

 custid = saving.getCustomerId();
System.out.println(custid);
m.addAttribute("customId",saving);


 System.out.println(saving.getDisgnProf());

 List<SavingBean> list = new ArrayList<SavingBean>();
 list.add(saving);

 return new ModelAndView("AccountInfo","list", list);
```

}
     @RequestMapping(value="/accinsert",method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView inserData(@ModelAttribute AccountBean accbean,HttpServletRequest rs,Model m) {

```
 SavingBean b = new SavingBean();

System.out.println("saas" +  b.getCustomerId());
session = rs.getSession();


System.out.println("xxx" + rs.getAttribute("customId"));
accbean.setCustid((Long) rs.getAttribute("customId"));
 AccountBean accbean1 = persionalService.insertacc(accbean);

 return new ModelAndView("welcome");
         }
```

Comment: but where u getting error i mean just make some changes in question and tell where in point u getting error?

Comment: System.out.println("bf" + rs.getAttribute("customId")); in this line getting null value

Comment: okey but u need to give model attribute name like this @ModelAttribute("xyz") where xyz will be model attribute that u sending from Jsp or UI page.

Answer (score 0):

From the first look to your code , I notice that your request method not specified. At this case (When using @ModelAttribute) you have to make it as (POST) request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@RequestMapping(value = "/accinsert" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Why ? because actually your object will be retrieved due to Form Submission which is treated as POST request. Try that thing and check the results. If the problem is still maybe you have some real problem in your Presentation Layer (e.g JSP Page) that is responsible about submitting the data.

Good Luck !

Comment: haseem I was trying that only previously but getting null at this line System.out.println("xxx" + session.getAttribute("customId"));

Comment: @NirrajSingh that line is not mentioned in your code !

Comment: @NirrajSingh it means you don't have session stored in the server ! that's why you got null , make sure the session is created !

Comment: @Hatem i think the problem is not about what u have given description.  this could be solution..  @ModelAttribute("xyz") where xyz will be model attribute that u sending from Jsp or UI page.

Comment: @NirrajSingh try this req.getParameter("id"); too.

Comment: Hatem you mean to saythe name of variable  xyz should be same as in jsp

Comment: @NirrajSingh not the same name of jsp but for example if u have used form tag of spring in that there is attribute of form spring that commandname or modelattribute that is what has to be same.

Comment: and one other thing is that if u adding into model like this m.addAttribute("customId",saving); then how u will be able to get it on other side? if u want to access that variable in other request then  u need to set attribute i mean req.setattribute(object,object) that is method.